# ngFor Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

Im trying to learn angular and Im following a code tutorial and as far as I can tell my code matches the instructors but it's not working.

I have the following code and it fails to compile saying the objects dont exist. what am i missing?

```
import { ThrowStmt } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  products:Object[];

  constructor() {
    this.products = [
        {
          id: "1",
          name:"Mac Book Pro"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          name:"iPhone"
        }
    ];
  }

  public getProducts(){
    return this.products;
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```
Product Details:

<div *ngFor="let product of products">
    <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
    <h1>{{product.id}}</h1>
</div>
```

it prints out [[object Object]] twice if i remove the .name and .id, but as it stands i get the following errors.

```
4     <h1>{{product.name}}{{product.id}}</h1>
                    ~~~~

  src/app/product/product.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './product.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component ProductComponent.


Error: src/app/product/product.component.html:4:35 - error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'.

4     <h1>{{product.name}}{{product.id}}</h1>
                                    ~~
```

**SOLVED**
I have solved the issue by changing from Object[] to any[].

products:any[];

this solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution 1

You have to **specify `products` type as the array with strongly typed class/interface** instead of `Object[]`;

> product.model.ts

```js
export interface Product {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

> product.component.ts

```js
import { Product } from '../models/product.model';
products: Product[];
```

[Sample Solution 1 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-db4gao)

---

### Solution 2

Alternative, change the text interpolation as below if you prefer `products` as `Object[]` type.

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products">
  <h1>{{product["name"]}}</h1>
  <h1>{{product["id"]}}</h1>
</div>
```

[Sample Solution 2 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9zgxd6)

Comment: Solution 2 did not work, it failed with the following error.

Error: src/app/product/product.component.html:4:11 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"name"' can't be used to index type 'Object'.

Comment: The issue of solution 2 would be due to the setting in `compilerOptions` in your tsconfig.json. You may use Solution 1 to specify the type with interface/class.

Comment: Solution 1 works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try using `?` operator, like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products">
    <h1>{{product?.name}}</h1>
    <h1>{{product?.id}}</h1>
</div>
```

Your current code will break if any product is missing `name` or `id` property.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was using the type Object[] Swapping to any[] solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change products:Object[]; to products:any[];
I.e the type should be any instead of Object. this is a general angular bug. Hope they resolve it.